# singleton setter thinks it's receiving an int *?

Tags: objective-c

I've got the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Game.h"

@interface World : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Game *game;

+(id)sharedInstance;

//---------------------------------------

#import "World.h"

@implementation World

@synthesize game = _game;

+(id)sharedInstance {
    DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK(^{
    return [[self alloc] init];
});
}
```

Yet when I try to set the game property:

```
-(id)initWithLevelIdentifier:(int)identifier {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.currentLevel = [[Level alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];
        // stuff

        [[World sharedInstance] setGame:self];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I get:
    "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'Game *__strong'"

Why does it think this is an int *, when it's clearly specified as a Game type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency here. I'm betting `Game.h` also imports `World.h`. See [@class vs. #import in header compile time saving with Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271146/class-vs-import-in-header-compile-time-saving-with-clang/7271910#7271910).

The solution is to just note in `World.h` that `Game` is a class, but not import the header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Game;    // <=== rather than #import

@interface World : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Game *game;

+(id)sharedInstance;
```

---

Note that your code here has a design problem as well. The mere act of creating a `Game` object changes the current `World` game. This means that it is very difficult to treat `Game` as a non-singleton (just creating it modifies global state), yet `Game` is not a singleton. This is very surprising behavior in an initialization method. It would be better to move the `setGame:` call outside of `init` and let the caller decide whether this is now the global current game. It would be reasonable to put this in `World` as  `-[World createNewGame]`.

Comment: Interesting comment..  You know, as far as it's designed now, game pretty much acts as a singleton.  It gets initialized, and then completing a level simply reassigns game.level to be the next level, etc..  So there are never multiple game objects.  Hence why I  thought storing game in the world singleton inside game's init  seemed logical... Does this seem like I should just make Game a singleton?  Or should I just go with what you suggested above?

Comment: It seems excessive to have both a singleton World and a singleton Game. I would have one of them be a singleton, and the other be owned by the singleton. You might also ask why there is a mutating "Game" object at all rather than a series of "Level" objects (that's just a question; I don't know whether your design is good or bad there).